# Post fullcalendar calendar.getevents() array object to bakend

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, fullcalendar

When I try to send fullcalendar events to my Django backend, it seems that AJAX is not sending the proper data. How can I send those events to the backend properly?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/home/update_event/',
  method: 'POST',
  data: calendar.getEvents(),
  success: (e) => {
    $('#information').text('Your event is saved')
  }
});
```

If I console.log the object it gives the following result:
[image: Screenshot]

For the Django side I am just trying to print out what request.POST contains... I wish to convert it to an array ideally.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    for n in request.POST:
        print(n)
```

Comment: What is the 'proper data'? What are you actually receiving? What does the Django code that's receiving the data look like? We need a lot more information here to be able to debug your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What I meant by proper code is that I should be able to extract the title, start date and end date. I am only trying to print the contents in request.POST but it seems the content posted by ajax is only undefined... @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Here is my code: `    if request.method == 'POST':
        for n in request.POST:
            print(n)`

Answer (score 1):

I think I get the point... I shall create an array myself from the getevents function.
Here is my code:

```
    var events = storeCalendar.getEvents()
    var data_arr = []
    events.forEach((item, index)=>{
        data_arr.push({
            'title':item.title,
            'start':item.start,
            'end':item.end,
            'description':item.description,
        })
    })
```

Then, use JSON.stringify(data_arr)

And finally, ajax post data to Django. Thanks to all who have once helped me with this issue!